# How do I return only duplicate values depending on column name?

Tags: sql, select

Im using Access for sql. I know access is terrible but its the only available resource for database in my work.

I want to return duplicate values for, lets say, the middle name. I want to see all the rows with the same middle names on a certain month.

Here comes the tricky part, the duplicate values i want to look for is not in the table. I wanna see the duplicate values when you concatenate middle name AND last name. )and for some reason, Access dont like aliases)

Comment: GROUP BY combined with HAVING COUNT > 1?

Comment: We need a table structure, sample data, and expected result. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by on concatenated value:

```
select middle_name || last_name
from names_table
group by middle_name || last_name
having count(*) > 1
```